# How can you iterate and change the values in a mutable array in Rust?

Tags: rust

This is how far I got:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
enum Suits {
    Hearts,
    Spades,
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct Card {
    card_num: u8,
    card_suit: Suits,
}

fn generate_deck() {
    let deck: [Option<Card>; 52] = [None; 52];

    for mut i in deck.iter() {
        i = &Some(Card {
            card_num: 1,
            card_suit: Suits::Hearts,
        });
    }

    for i in deck.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    generate_deck();
}
```

It only  prints out `None`. Is there something wrong with my borrowing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `iter` => `iter_mut` - - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b0c99b7fc83bfdef5af4eca1dd4b22a

Comment: One of the clues about your mistake is in the output: _"warning: value assigned to `i` is never read"_, for the line: `i = &Some(Card {`. It's not being read anywhere so the mutation is not having any effect. You are writing a new reference to a variable, and _not_ giving the existing reference a new value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your deck is not mutable. Remember in rust bindings are non-mutable by default:

```
let mut deck: [Option<Card>; 52] = [None; 52];
```

Next, to obtain an iterator you can modify, you use `iter_mut()`:

```
for i in deck.iter_mut() {
```

Finally: the `i` that you have in your loop is a mutable reference to the elements of deck. To assign something to the reference, you need to dereference it:

```
*i = Some(Card {
    card_num: 1,
    card_suit: Suits::Hearts,
});
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a92bedc5b27a4591762b326b1a277315)